# How to change success color of BootstrapValidator?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator

How do I go about to change the validation color of the label when a field has been validated? when a field is validated it looks like this...
[image: On Successful validation]

I would rather have the label "Username" be its standard black when its successfully validated, I looked through the js file and the css file, but am not sure where to change the color. Has anyone ran into this issue before and if so, how did and where were you able to change the color?

Answer (score 0):

When the status is valid , it will add has-success class ,

it will be found in the bootstrap.css

just update the following css :

.has-success .form-control

.has-success .input-group-addon